# Help me find this robot cartoon character

Tags: character-identification, cartoon

What is the name of the cartoon that the robot in the red box is from?

[image: robot, space ,aliens]

Answer (score 11):

### MEGAS, from *Megas XLR*

[*Megas XLR*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361201/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) was produced by Cartoon Network and aired for about nine months as part of Toonami.

[image]

[image]

MEGAS is a mech suit from the 31st century which gets accidentally sent back in time to the 21st century. It falls into the hands of two characters voiced by [David DeLuise](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0217936/) (the substantially less-famous son of comedian Dom DeLouise) and [Steve Blum](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0089710/) who, naturally, give it a totally radical paint job.

Despite this truly incredible premise, not many people watched the show and Cartoon Network swiftly cancelled it.

You can watch the show's opening theme (and many episodes, as well) on YouTube; behold, and ask yourself if you truly dig giant robots:

Comment: The Megas Robot has some great weapons, including an accurately depicted Wave Motion Cannon!